# Can you import c++ code into a VSCode extension?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm rewriting an old product (written in C++) as a new VSCode extension. The UI part is going to be redesigned and implemented using Typescript.

Is it possible to somehow salvage the functionality logic and invoke it somehow (e.g. wrap it in some library and use it)?
If it's possible, would the solution work for both Windows and Linux VSCode use?

Comment: simple answer: No. VSC is JavaScript based, You can look at the language servers that are implemented as a separate process. Can you extend NodeJS with your C++?

Comment: thanks. Can you please elaborate on your last sentence? I was not aware VSCode is implemented as a NodeJS env

Comment: Electron is a NodeJS application, and VSC is based on Electron